# C# SQL Server query UPDATE/DELETE

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm making a contact list using C# and SQL Server, but these statements are throwing an exception

```
SqlCommand smd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE contacts SET Name = '" + newName + "', Number = '" + newNumber + "' WHERE Name = " +nameToUpdate + "", cn);

SqlCommand smd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM contacts WHERE Name = " + nameToDelete + "", cn);
```

> Invalid Column Name 'nameToUpdate/nameToDelete'

Comment: please don't do string concat like that to add values into a sql statement. SQL Injection errors will hunt you forever.

Comment: @rene can you give the statement, I', quite new to this

Comment: You're missing quotes in `where name = '" + nameToDelete + "'"` ... please don't fix it like this. Lookup how to use SqlParameters.

Comment: @rene While the accepted answer in the question you referred to as a duplicate, does in principle also answer this question, it does make use of AddWithValue, which is considered [bad practice](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) for quite a while now

Comment: @derpirscher I'm happy to add a better dupe if you have one for me. I tried to find one that kind of started with the same problem the OP and then solves it into a better direction then my earlier comment did. I'm aware of the bad practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider your query

```
"UPDATE myTable SET mycolumn =  '"+newvalue+"' WHERE mycolumn = "+ oldvalue;
```

This becomes the following query sent to SQL Server

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn = 'John' WHERE mycolumn = bob;
```

You see the error? There are quotes missing around `bob`. Furthermore, consider your new name is something like `John O'Brian` what do you think, will happen to your query?

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn = 'John O'Brian' WHERE mycolumn = bob;
```

This is, obviously, invalid syntax.

Therefore you should NEVER create queries like that, but use paramterized queries. This will make your apps more robust (ie it's not throwing errors like the above) and secure (ie will prevent SQL injections). And it's much easier to write, read and maintain, because you don't have to care about quotes and such things anymore.

```
 var cmd = new SqlCommand("update table mytable set mycolumn = @newvalue where mycolumn = @oldvalue", connection);
 cmd.AddParam("@newvalue", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "john";
 cmd.AddParam("@oldvalue", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "bob";
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: What would be the statement for search query? If I want to search a row from its name

Comment: Yes, same principle ...

Comment: The only think I find missing is that parametrized queries make repetitive queries perform faster because they reuse the execution plan of the database (unless the plan is poorly generated) It is a win-win: less errors, more readable, faster execution